# Netplan does not clean old routes when changing route configuration

Tags: linux, networking, systemd, routing, netplan

I have a `netplan` configuration file:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      routes:
        - to: 192.168.202.0/24
          via: 192.168.201.98
```

Note: addresses are configured in another file

After `netplan apply` the route is added to the routing table:

```
# ip r
default via 192.168.201.1 dev eth0 proto static 
192.168.201.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.201.56 
192.168.202.0/24 via 192.168.201.98 dev eth0 proto static // <------- HERE
```

When **changing** this configuration file to

```
          via: 192.168.201.97
```

Instead of `via: 192.168.201.98`, loading `netplan apply` + `ip r` gives me this:

```
# ip r
default via 192.168.201.1 dev eth0 proto static 
192.168.201.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.201.56 
192.168.202.0/24 via 192.168.201.98 dev eth0 proto static  // <------- OLD
192.168.202.0/24 via 192.168.201.97 dev eth0 proto static  // <------- NEW
```

As you can see, the old route `192.168.202.0/24 via 192.168.201.98 dev eth0 proto static` is still there while it shouldn't. I would expect this route to be removed.
BTW, this is how it works when changing `addresses` in netplan config file - it doesn't add the new address and keep the old - it removes and old and add the new.

Is there a way to make netplan set the exact routes as in the configuration files? or run a command to clean routes before `netplan apply` ?
What should be the appropriate process?

Thanks

Comment: Really strange, adding this duplicate route (with same metric: 0) should not even be allowed with rtnetlink (ie: `ip route`). Older API (using `route`) would "work" but not result in the property `proto static`.